# UIDatePicker not showing in right place on UITable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a UITableCell and on that cell i have a UITextBox, when the textbox is clicked instead of a keyboard being shown, a UIDatePicker is being displayed with the code below. But i am having trouble positioning the UIDatePicker. I need it to start from the very bottom of the page at at the moment it appears to start from the top of the table section where the textbox was pressed. The code fires when the user clicks the Preferred Date label. Any pointers? I have attached an image to show where it is currently rendering. Thanks.

[image: Issue]

```
- (IBAction)selectDateBegin:(id)sender {


    //Disable Keyboard
    [self.txtBookingDate resignFirstResponder];
    //Disable Scrolling
    [_tableForm setScrollEnabled:false];

    if ([self.view viewWithTag:9]) {
        return;
    }
    CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
    CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);

    UIView *darkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    darkView.alpha = 0;
    darkView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    darkView.tag = 9;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)] ;
    [darkView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.view addSubview:darkView];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)] ;
    datePicker.tag = 10;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 44)];
    toolBar.tag = 11;
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDatePicker:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, doneButton, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveIn" context:nil];
    toolBar.frame = toolbarTargetFrame;
    datePicker.frame = datePickerTargetFrame;
    darkView.alpha = 0.5;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suggest you to do is replacing the inputView of your textField (the default is the keyboard) with this instruction:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init] ;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[preferredDateField setInputView:datePicker];
```

It is more appropriate and in compliance with Apple Human Interface Guideline

Comment: Thanks @Lolloz89 ill do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it that way. Create a date picker and set it as the `inputView` of your text field. Then the system will present it for you, in the right place, with the right animation, instead of the keyboard.